# Dynamic filter based on the config and user : PySpark

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyspark

Need to apply the filters dynamically based on the filters from two places. (1) config (2) user/job input

Required Filter to be applied: (1) whatever the filters mentioned in the config.filters and (2) user supplied filter ie number of days based on the run date. ie rundate-history_days.
If user passes the rundate as 2020-01-20 and history_days as 5, then final filter should be :

```
 cust=123 and (activity_day between rundate and rundate-5)
```

I was able to achive this using two step filters.
(1) using sql way of filter from the config df.filter(config['config'])
(2) 2nd round of filter on top of 1 using
`activity_day>=date_sub(rundate,history_days) & activity_day<rundate`

Is there anyway I can merge two step filter into one? so that I can maintain both the filters in config and somehow substitute user input?

Data:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
        [
          (123,"2020-01-01"),
          (124,"2020-01-01"),
          (123,"2019-01-01")
        ],
        ("cust", "activity_day")
    )
```

Config:

```
config = """
                [ {
                      "source":"df_1",
                      "filters":"cust=123",
                  }
                ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start by parsing your config to extract the filter condition 'filters`and the corresponding value into a dictionary and add the`run_date`condition to it to further filter the`DataFrame`

##### Data Preparation

```
sparkDF = sql.createDataFrame(
        [
          (123,"2020-01-01"),
          (124,"2020-01-01"),
          (123,"2019-01-01")
        ],
        ("cust", "activity_day")
    )

sparkDF.show()

+----+------------+
|cust|activity_day|
+----+------------+
| 123|  2020-01-01|
| 124|  2020-01-01|
| 123|  2019-01-01|
+----+------------+
```

##### Parsing Config and Generating Filter Condn

```
config = [ {"source":"df_1","filters":"cust=123",}]

filter_dict = {}

for row in config:
    if 'filters' in row:
        key,value = row['filters'].split("=")
        filter_dict[key] = value

filter_dict

{'cust': '123'}

run_date = "2020-01-01"

upper_range = F.to_date(F.lit(run_date))
lower_range = F.date_add(upper_range,-5)

secondary_condn = (F.col('activity_day').between(lower_range,upper_range))

final_condn = (F.col(column) == filter_dict[column]) & (secondary_condn)
```

##### Filtering DataFrame

```
sparkDF.filter(final_condn).show()

+----+------------+
|cust|activity_day|
+----+------------+
| 123|  2020-01-01|
+----+------------+
```

###### SQL Approach Toward multiple conditions

You can utilise [createOrReplaceTempView](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.createOrReplaceTempView.html) for more complex filters. The idea is to build `WHERE` filter(s) to merge it to a `SQL` query to filter the rows

```
sparkDF = sql.createDataFrame(
        [
          (123,"2020-01-01",1,"NL"),
          (124,"2020-01-01",0,"US"),
          (123,"2019-01-01",1,"IN"),
          (124,"2020-01-02",0,"NL"),
        ],
        ("cust", "activity_day","is_deleted","country")
    )

sparkDF.show()

+----+------------+----------+-------+
|cust|activity_day|is_deleted|country|
+----+------------+----------+-------+
| 123|  2020-01-01|         1|     NL|
| 124|  2020-01-01|         0|     US|
| 123|  2019-01-01|         1|     IN|
| 124|  2020-01-02|         0|     NL|
+----+------------+----------+-------+

where_filter = ""
logical_flag = " OR "

for i,row in enumerate(config):
    if 'filters' in row:
        if i == 0:
            where_filter += row['filters']
        else:
            where_filter += logical_flag + "(" + row['filters'] + ")"

where_filter # O/P -- 'cust=123 OR (is_deleted != 1 AND country="NL")'

if where_filter != "":
    sql.sql(f"""
        SELECT *
        FROM customer_activity
        WHERE {where_filter}
    """).show()

+----+------------+----------+-------+
|cust|activity_day|is_deleted|country|
+----+------------+----------+-------+
| 123|  2020-01-01|         1|     NL|
| 123|  2019-01-01|         1|     IN|
| 124|  2020-01-02|         0|     NL|
+----+------------+----------+-------+
```

Comment: how do we handle if the filter string in the config is complex - for ex: "filters":"is_deleted != 1 and  and country=NL"? are there any better ways to structure the filter in config instead of sql way to combine both config filter and user input filter?

Comment: Updated the answer to demonstrate the same , do upvote the answer as well if it helped you